# How optimize web app for mobile ( ext js modern)

Tags: javascript, android, extjs, web-applications, sencha-touch

We have created test versions of web apps. Development was carried out in the modern extjs framework (`6.2.0`). So this means that apps must be cross platform. But when the app is used by a mobile phone I am faced with the following things:

1. In iOS phones the page does not load (after a couple of seconds there is an error). In Safari and Chrome.
2. Extjs objects look bad in different android devices: forms are too big or too small for this display. Page (this app is a single page app) is loaded slowly..

**UPD:**
IOS 12 safari error message:

> A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded.

I get a bad view when I use Xaomi Redmi 4 Note or Huawei P10 on version 7 and 8  of Android accordingly.

**Questions**

1. What config defines Action Sheet size and Action Sheet's font characteristics?
2. How to define characteristics of select field menu ( size and layout)?
3. What is the reason of app's working wrongly on iOS browsers?
4. Some links with suggestions or examples of multiplatform development on extjs

Thanks to all stackoverflow users!

Comment: If you have errors on iOS than share the error. If you have problem with "different android device" share the name of the device an android version.

Comment: Thanks for suggest. For ios 12 safari Error Message: A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded. Bad view when i use xaomi redmi 4 note and huawei p 10 on 7 and 8 version of android accordingly